# How do I break out of javascript loop based on response from AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

My topic has been covered extensively here. I have searched alot and tried alot of code but have not found anything that helps me solve my specific situation. So I would like to pose this question to the community.

I am building a page with 12 form fields where I loop through the fields and make an AJAX call to test the value against a database. My issue is that I need to stop my loop and get user input based on a particular response from my AJAX call. So far I have been unable to stop my loop until it reaches the end.

Here is my form:

```
<form name="claimForm">
<table>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode1"></td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode2"></td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode3"></td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode4"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode5"></td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode6"></td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode7"></td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode8"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="icdcode9"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode10"></td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode11"></td>
<td> <input type="text" id="icdcode12"></td>

</tr>

<tr> <td colspan="4"> <input type="button" value="Check IDC Code" onClick="javascript:claimValidate();"></td></tr>
</table>


</form>

<div id="pageresponse"></span>
```

Here is my claimValidate function:

```
function claimValidate() {

var isFound = false; 
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

    var icdcode = 'icdcode'+i;

    if (!isFound) {
        if(document.getElementById(icdcode)) {
            var retrieved = document.getElementById(icdcode).value;

                if (retrieved != "") {

                       if (ajaxCheck(retrieved)) {

                        }


                } // end if retrieved

        } // end if document.getElementbyId
    } // end if !isFound    



} // end claimValidate
```

And here is my ajaxCheck function

```
function ajaxCheck(icdcode) {

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            //alert(isFound)
            resp = xmlhttp.responseText;

            if (resp == icdcode) {
                return true;
            } else if (resp == "Search Failed") {
                alert("You must enter a valid issue code.")
                return false;
            }  // end if resp

        if ((resp !== "Search Failed") && (resp.length > 0)) { 
                document.getElementById("pageresponse").innerHTML = resp;
                return false;
            }

        } // end readystate

    } // end onreadystatechange

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "validate_idc_code.asp?q=" + icdcode, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

} // end ajaxCheck
```

My intent is to break out of the loop and stop if it gets to the final if statement in ajaxCheck but it is not and I'm not sure why. I showed my code to a co-worker and he seemed to think that ajaxCheck would not actually return anything because it was being called in a separate function. He suggested passing all my form fields as an array to the ASP page I have doing the database check, but I'm not sure that is the best solution.

I would be grateful for any guidance the experts out there could provide for me.

Thank you!

-- Chris

Comment: You mention it's been covered extensively here, have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)?  Essentially your `ajaxCheck` function cannot return a value to be used within the loop in this way.  You'll need to restructure somewhat.

Comment: you can't, unless you switch to using a synchronous call, or splitting your logic so the "got a response" logic is executed in the ajax call's success handler.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had not seen the article that @James Thorpe linked to. That looks to be a good way of handling what I want to accomplish. I will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it by using a global var indicating that you want your loop to continue or stop.
then in claimValidate you would put something like

```
if (!loopActive) return;
```

But this is a bad practice. The best is restructuring like @MarcB and @JamesThorpe had adviced.

I only answered with this ideia, because I understand that in order to learn anything you have to progress initially in not the best way and then progressively understand why that is not the best practice.

Comment: This will only work if the requests are synchronous (which you really want to avoid anyway - they're being deprecated and may be removed at some point).  With asynchronous requests, you'll find that the entire loop runs before the first ajax request has come back.